# How to initialize a property in iOS UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, lazy-initialization

I am working on a `UITableViewController`

```
@interface GinkgoDeliveryOrdersTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property PFQuery * query;
@property NSArray * products;

@end
```

How shall I initialize these two properties? Currently, I am doing lazy initialization:

```
@implementation GinkgoDeliveryOrdersTableViewController

@synthesize query = _query;
@synthesize products = _products;

- (void) initQuery {
    _query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_Product"];
}

- (void) initProducts {
    if(! _query)
        [self initQuery];
    _products = [_query findObjects];
}
```

As a result, every time I want to use these two properties, I have to do something like this:

```
if(! self.products)
        [self initProducts];
```

and

```
if(! self.query)
        [self initQuery];
```

I feel I am doing something wrong here. Is there a cleaner way to do this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the values are not being set from the outside then they shouldn't be read/write properties. Make them read-only and use lazy loading in the "getter" method.

```
@interface GinkgoDeliveryOrdersTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, readonly) PFQuery * query;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray * products;

@end


@implementation GinkgoDeliveryOrdersTableViewController

@synthesize query = _query;
@synthesize products = _products;

- (PFQuery *)query {
    if (!_query) {
        _query = ...
    }

    return _query;
}
```

Do the same for the `products` getter.

Note that in your original code there was no need for the `@synthesize` lines but in this updated code they are needed because otherwise the ivar wouldn't be auto generated due to the explicit getter method.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a `@property` the compiler creates setters and getters for you automatically.

```
// Let's say you create a public property in your header file (.h)
@property NSObject *var;

// You synthesize your property in your implementation file (.m)
@synthesize var = _var;

// What does the compiler creates for you?
// A getter that by default has the same name as your variable 
- (NSObject *)var
{
    return _var;
}

// A setter that by default is called "set" + "Var" (your variable name with first letter in uppercase)
- (void)setVar:(NSObject *)var
{
    _var = var;
}
```

Lazy instantiation is a design pattern where you chose to wait until the very last moment to instantiate your objects. So, in your case, it would be in the `getter`. When someone tries to read a property that was not yet used it is time to instantiate them :D

This is what I think you want :D

```
// GinkgoDeliveryOrdersTableViewController.h
@interface GinkgoDeliveryOrdersTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property PFQuery *query;
@property NSArray *products;

@end

// GinkgoDeliveryOrdersTableViewController.m
@implementation GinkgoDeliveryOrdersTableViewController

@synthesize query = _query;
@synthesize products = _products;

// SETTERS
- (void)setQuery:(PFQuery *)query {
    _query = query;
}

- (void)setQuery:(NSArray *)products {
    _products = array;
}

// GETTERS
- (PFQuery *)query {
    if (!_query)
        _query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_Product"];

    return _query;
}

- (NSArray *)products {
    if (!_products)
        _products = [_query findObjects];

    return _products;
}
```

- `@synthesize` for primitive types allocates the space required for the variable.
- `@synthesize` for pointers to objects allocates the space required for the pointer only. You have to allocate and initialize your property.
- Do not use `_var` outside of setters and getters. Use self.var instead.
- you can change the default name for your setter and getter

`@property (nonatomic, strong, setter=setVariable:, getter=getVariable) NSObject *var;`

- rmaddy has the perfect answer... but I had mine saved as a draft already... I'll be faster to answer next time...